# Convert json file to dynamic table using jquery

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following code to load json file and convert it to table,I am getting error `roleList is not defined`.What I did wrong?

Is my code correct?

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
                // var roleList;
          $.getJSON('a.json', function(data) {
           var roleList=data;
           // console.log(rolelist);
              empRoles();  
          });
    });
    function empRoles(){
  for(var i=0;i<roleList.length;i++)
     {
     var table='<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>'+roleList[i].sNo+'</td><td class="roleName" id="name'+i+'">'+roleList[i].roleName+'</td><td><button class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit'+i+'"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button class="btn update btn-success" id="update'+i+'"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
     $('#roleListTable').append(table)
     }
}
```

This is a.json file:

```
var data=[{
"sNo"     :"1",
"roleName":"Designer"
},
{
"sNo"     :"2",
"roleName":"Developer"
},
{
"sNo"     :"3",
"roleName":"HR Dept"
},
{
"sNo"     :"4",
"roleName":"Project Manager"
}
];
```

Html part:

```
                <table class="table">
                <thead class="roleListTableHead">
                <tr>
                <td>S.NO</td>
                <td>ROLE NAME</td>
                <td>ACTION</td>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="roleListTable">
                </tbody>            
                </table>
```

Can anyone give idea?

Comment: tried [`parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)?

Comment: @Vishal kumar No I did't try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass `roleList` as an argument to `empRoles()` function.

```js
var roleList = [{
    "sNo": "1",
    "roleName": "Designer"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "2",
    "roleName": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "3",
    "roleName": "HR Dept"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "4",
    "roleName": "Project Manager"
  }
];

empRoles(roleList);

function empRoles(roleList) {
  for (var i = 0; i < roleList.length; i++) {
    var table = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + roleList[i].sNo + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList[i].roleName + '</td><td><button class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button class="btn update btn-success" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
    $('#roleListTable').append(table)
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">
  <thead class="roleListTableHead">
    <tr>
      <td>S.NO</td>
      <td>ROLE NAME</td>
      <td>ACTION</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="roleListTable">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

You need to remove `var data=` from `a.json` file, the data structure for the JSON file not correct. See working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/eyyJPK?p=preview)

Comment: @user7397787, there nothing wrong in the other code

Comment: @user7397787, Are you getting the data? check `console.log(roleList)`

Comment: please check this with above json file.

Comment: @user7397787 You need to remove `var data=` from `a.json` file. see https://plnkr.co/edit/eyyJPK?p=preview

Comment: yah yah thanks.Now I am getting data but table only not displaying

Answer (score 1):

Use a `each()` loop, pass your data to the function as a argument

```
     $.getJSON('a.json', function(data) {
        empRoles(data);  
     });
     function empRoles(data) {
       $.each(data,function(i,roleList) {
        var table = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + roleList.sNo + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList.roleName + '</td><td><button class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button class="btn update btn-success" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
        $('#roleListTable').append(table)
       });
      }
```

```js
var data = [{
    "sNo": "1",
    "roleName": "Designer"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "2",
    "roleName": "Developer"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "3",
    "roleName": "HR Dept"
  },
  {
    "sNo": "4",
    "roleName": "Project Manager"
  }
];

function empRoles(data) {
  $.each(data,function(i,roleList) {
    var table = '<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' + roleList.sNo + '</td><td class="roleName" id="name' + i + '">' + roleList.roleName + '</td><td><button class="btn edit btn-info" id="edit' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>Edit</button><button class="btn update btn-success" id="update' + i + '"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>Update</button><button class="btn dlt btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>Delete</button></td><tr>';
    $('#roleListTable').append(table)
  });
}

empRoles(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="roleListTable"></div>
```

Comment: I want to load separate json file.

Comment: you can do that